# Using Powershell called from a bat file, Need to get owner/user of a windows process, but owner isn't showing up

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I need to get the path and owner of certain processes on a remote computer and use a batch file to get it.  So far, I've come up with something that gives me the path, but not the owner:

```
powershell -command "Get-WmiObject -Class win32_process -ComputerName myserver.mydomain.local -Filter 'name like """"%%myprocess%%""""' | select path,GetOwner"
```

For that, GetOwner is blank.

How can I get this to work or accomplish the same objective with another PS query or batch command?

Comment: Try ```powershell -command "get-acl $(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_process -ComputerName myserver.mydomain.local -Filter 'name like """"%%myprocess%%""""''.Path | select 'owner'"```

Comment: I don't think `getowner` is a part of `Get-WmiObject` but if you use `get-acl` on the path of the object you can select the owner from there.

Comment: GetOwner is a method, not a property.

Comment: @NekoMusume, tried that and got:
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Answer (score 0):

GetOwner() is a method.  User is a property returned by getowner() that is probably what you want.

```
set myprocess=powershell
powershell "Get-WmiObject win32_process -computername myserver.mydomain.local | where name -match %myprocess% | select path,@{n='Owner';e={$_.getowner().user}}"

Path                                                      Owner
----                                                      -----
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe admin
```

Or you can use get-process.  EDIT:  Hmm looks like -computername and -includeusername can't go together.  I can test it with "%computername%" but not "localhost".

```
powershell "get-process -computername %computername% -includeusername *%myprocess%* | select path,username"

Get-Process : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-process -computername DESKTOP-JQ7B7TZ -includeusername *powershel ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
```

If remote powershell were working:

```
powershell "invoke-command myserver.mydomain.local { get-process -includeusername *%myprocess%* | select path,username }"

Path           : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
UserName       : DESKTOP-JQ7B7TZ\admin
PSComputerName : myserver.mydomain.local
RunspaceId     : b1bc87a7-1c21-4f91-a238-bbb68978ea6c
```

Comment: Tried the first one and got:
where : The specified operator requires both the -Property and -Value parameters. Provide values for both parameters,
and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:69
+ ... ess -computername myserver.mydomain.local | where name -match  | sele ...
+                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ValueNotSpecifiedForWhereObject,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand

Comment: It was like it didn't even get the match value

Comment: Tried the second version and got:
Get-Process : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-process -computername myserver.mydomain.local -includeusername ** ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand

Comment: With the first one, I'm assuming my myprocess is set to something in the .bat file, like your example.  You're right about the second one.